# Member template alias to another template member

Tags: c++, c++14

Template alias to the template with some template arguments substituted can be achieved following way:

```
template <typename T, ConvertFunction<T> F>
Result<> Convert(Chain& chain, T& field)
{
// ... Some unimportant body
}

template <typename T>
constexpr Result<>(*ConvertHex)(Chain& chain, T& field) = &ConvertNextTokenTo<T, HexTo<T>>;
template <typename T>
constexpr Result<>(*ConvertDec)(Chain& chain, T& field) = &ConvertNextTokenTo<T, IntTo<T>>;
```

That is achievable in the global scope. Very useful feature.

My question is, however, how to achieve similar aliasing within a class?

```
template <class M>
class FooBar
{
   Result<M> m_result;
   chain& m_chain;

   template <typename T, ConvertFunction<T> F>
   MessageFromChain<M>& NextTo(T M::* memberPtr)
   {
   // ... Some unimportant body
   }

   // What put here?
};
```

Currently I've just created new members:

```
   template <typename T>
   FooBar<M>& NextDecTo(T M::* memberPtr)
   {
      return NextTo<T, IntTo<T>>(memberPtr);
   }

   template <typename T>
   FooBar<M>& NextHexTo(T M::* memberPtr)
   {
      return NextTo<T, HexTo<T>>(memberPtr);
   }
```

But is is possible to achieve that by aliases? I've tried multiple variants if they compile, they don't work. Thanks for answer if it's even possible. Please don't **unnecessarily** comment if the approach I already used is OK as I'm going to stick to it regardless the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> But is is possible to achieve that by aliases?

No, as far I know.

What do you call "aliases" are template variables, available starting from C++14.
And template variables can't be not static method in class/structs.

So, if `NextTo()` can be written as template static method, I suppose you can write a couple of template static aliases (method pointer).

If `NextTo()` has to be a not-static template method, I don't think it's possible what you asked.